# How to wait until React component completely finished updating in Jest and/or Enzyme?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, asynchronous, jestjs, enzyme

In my create-react-app, I am trying to test a component that does multiple `setState`s when mounted.

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {

  state = {
    a: undefined,
    b: undefined,
    c: undefined,
  };

  fetchA() {
    // returns a promise
  }

  fetchB() {
    // returns a promise
  }

  fetchC() {
    // returns a promise
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    const a = await fetchA();
    this.setState({ a });
  }

  async componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (prevState.a !== this.state.a) {
      const [b, c] = await Promise.all([
        this.fetchB(a);
        this.fetchC(a);
      ]);
      this.setState({ b, c });
    }
  }

  ...

}
```

In my test, I do something like this, trying to let the `setState` in `componentDidUpdate` to finish before making assertions.

```
import { mount } from 'enzyme';

describe('MyComponent', () => {

  const fakeA = Promise.resolve('a');
  const fakeB = Promise.resolve('b');
  const fakeC = Promise.resolve('c');

  MyComponent.prototype.fetchA = jest.fn(() => fakeA);
  MyComponent.prototype.fetchB = jest.fn(() => fakeB);
  MyComponent.prototype.fetchC = jest.fn(() => fakeC);

  it('sets needed state', async () => {
    const wrapper = mount(<MyComponent />);
    await Promise.all([ fakeA, fakeB, fakeC ]);
    expect(wrapper.state()).toEqual({
      a: 'a',
      b: 'b',
      c: 'c',
    });
  });

});
```

Here's the interesting part: My test above will fail because the last `setState` call (in `componentDidUpdate`) has not finished when the assertion is made. At that time, `state.a` is set, but `state.b` and `state.c` is not set yet.

The only way I could make it work is by wedging `await Promise.resolve(null)` right before the assertion to give the last `setState` that extra tick/cycle to complete. This looks too hacky.

Another thing I've tried is wrapping the assertion in `setImmediate()`, which works fine as long as the assertion passes. If it fails, it will terminate the whole test because of uncaught error.

Has anyone overcome this problem?

Comment: Would it work if you replace `Promise.all` statement with two statements, like `const b = await this.fetchB(a) ...`? Or maybe mock `Promise.all`. My guess is, that problem is the the promise you create there, that jest don't know about.

Comment: Are you referring to the `Promise.all` in the component or in the test? If it's in the test, I'm pretty sure I confirm that jest waits for all three to finish. However, the test resumes _as soon as_ the 3 promises finish, without waiting for the last `setState` in `componentDidUpdate` to finish. Regardless, I'll try playing with what you said.

Comment: Did you solve this problem ?

Comment: Yes. Look at the answer I posted below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is how I solved it. Hope that helps someone.

```
import { mount } from 'enzyme';

describe('MyComponent', () => {

  const fakeA = Promise.resolve('a');
  const fakeB = Promise.resolve('b');
  const fakeC = Promise.resolve('c');

  MyComponent.prototype.fetchA = jest.fn(() => fakeA);
  MyComponent.prototype.fetchB = jest.fn(() => fakeB);
  MyComponent.prototype.fetchC = jest.fn(() => fakeC);

  it('sets needed state', async (done) => {
    const wrapper = mount(<MyComponent />);
    await Promise.all([ fakeA, fakeB, fakeC ]);

    setImmediate(() => {
      // Without the try catch, failed expect will cause the
      // whole test to crash out.
      try {
        expect(wrapper.state()).toEqual({
          a: 'a',
          b: 'b',
          c: 'c',
        });
      } catch(error) {
         done.fail(error);
      }
      done();

  });

});
```

Comment: The best approach would be to test the output of the component, and not it's internal state. For a good test it should be able to allow you to refactor the internals without affecting the output and test.

Comment: @OmriLuzon I agree with your point but often the output won't change until the internal state has updated. How would one know the state has updated before testing the output?

Comment: an explanation as to why this works would be more helpful. I mean why `setImmediate()` makes it work. After all, it executes the closure immediately, so it's the same thing as the code in the question. What difference does `setImmediate` make?